# Appending MySQL table row using Spark SQL dataframe write method

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie in Apache Spark SQL. Below is the codes of Spark SQL application and the results of query.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL Test")
                .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();      

Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connectionProperties.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
connectionProperties.put("user", "root");
connectionProperties.put("password", "password");

Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read().jdbc(connectionProperties.getProperty("url"), "family", connectionProperties);
jdbcDF.show();
jdbcDF.printSchema();
```

And the results are

```
+------+----------+--------+-------+
|EMP_ID|EMP_PASSWD|EMP_NAME|EMP_AGE|
+------+----------+--------+-------+
|  jina|       bbb|    mother|     45|
|joseph|       aaa|    father|     50|
|julian|       ccc|      son |     20|
+------+----------+--------+-------+


root
 |-- EMP_ID: string (nullable = false)
 |-- EMP_PASSWD: string (nullable = false)
 |-- EMP_NAME: string (nullable = false)
 |-- EMP_AGE: integer (nullable = false)
```

And I try to append the another row into family table. First I use sql command like below

```
Dataset<Row> appendSql = spark.sql("INSERT INTO family VALUES('jane' , 'ddd', 'daughter' , 15)");
```

Then I can bring the result which I want.

```
+------+----------+--------+-------+
|EMP_ID|EMP_PASSWD|EMP_NAME|EMP_AGE|
+------+----------+--------+-------+
|  jane|       ddd|daughter|     15|
|  jina|       bbb|  mother|     45|
|joseph|       aaa|  father|     50|
|julian|       ccc|     son|     20|
+------+----------+--------+-------+
```

And then I use write method like below

```
List<Object> appendData = Arrays.asList("julia", "eee", "grand mother", new Integer(70)); 
spark.createDataFrame(appendData, Object.class).write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(connectionProperties.getProperty("url"), "family", connectionProperties);
```

But the above line throws the following exception

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'EMP_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:970)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'EMP_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1756)
    ... 15 more
```

I try not to use StructField interface because DataTypes of column is simple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved with these below codes.

```
List<String> appendData = new ArrayList<String>();
appendData.add("julia,eee,grandmother 2,70");
appendData.add("jane,ddd,daughter ,15");

Dataset<Row> df_1 = spark.createDataset(appendData, Encoders.STRING()).toDF();
Dataset<Row> df_2 = df_1.selectExpr("split(value, ',')[0] as EMP_ID", "split(value, ',')[1] as EMP_PASSWD" , "split(value, ',')[2] as EMP_NAME", "split(value, ',')[3] as EMP_AGE");

df_2.show();

 df_2.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(connectionProperties.getProperty("url"), "family", connectionProperties);
```